# Docker Swarm installation. Connect: no route to host error

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

Need to setup a 3 node (D1, D2 & D3) docker cluster using swarm and install ElasticSearch & Kibana with each node on respective Oracle virtual Linux ( 7.4). D1 is Master node and D2, D3 worker nodes

Once docker engine is installed. Followed [this document](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/swarm-tutorial/create-swarm/) to create a swarm. However , while executing the command on D2 or D3 gets below error:

Command: `sudo docker swarm join --token <Token-ID> <IP>:2377`

Error: `Error response from daemon: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = all SubConns are in TransientFailure, latest connection error: connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp <IP>:2377: connect: no route to host"`

All theses node servers are on the same network and no firewall restrictions.
**`sudo netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN`** shows ports 2377, 7946 are listening but don’t see port 4789 as mentioned [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/swarm-tutorial/).

Please assist.

Comment: You've hidden the important part - the IP. Nevermind the firewall it seems from the error that the given IP has no routing between the servers. But, you know, we can't see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved it by running below on master node:

sudo systemctl stop firewalld.service

firewalld is a zone-based(host) customizable firewall and the above command disables the service until reboot